# Why the $ character is a problem for the parse_ini_file function in PHP

Tags: php, ini, php-7.4

I come to you because to transform an ini file into an array, I use the [parse_ini_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function provided by PHP.

**Extract from the ini file I want to retrieve**

```
SocEnCoursBD=001
SocEnCoursBS=001
SocEnCours$$=001
SocEnCoursLOG=001
SocEnCoursLOV=010
```

Unfortunately, the `parse_ini_file` function generates on the `SocEnCours$$=001`  line.

**Error thrown** :

```
syntax error, unexpected '$'
```

It looks like it doesn't support the `$` character. I know that PHP does not support this character and that's why I use the option [INI_SCANNER_RAW](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-ini-file.php) when calling the `parse_ini_file` function.

Enfin voici le bout de code PHP qui traite le fichier ini :

```php
    public static function parse(string $path) : array {
        return file_exists($path) ? parse_ini_file($path, true, INI_SCANNER_RAW) : null;
    }
```

To add I use PHP 7.4. If someone has a solution, I would be interested ^^

Comment: @axiac no, I tried the solution I proposed but the error is still there

Comment: I'm not sure that dollar signs are valid in INI files at all, no matter what language. I'm not able to find a definite answer on that, though.

Comment: use file_get_contents, pass though `str_replace('$$=', '__=', ` then use parse_ini_string, and then access like `$parsed['SocEnCours__']` or fix the source .ini file

Comment: The answer to the question is "it doesn't matter, that's the rule".

Comment: @LawrenceCherone this could be a solution that could work, I will try

Comment: @aynber I don't think INI files are properly specified at all. It's a proprietary MS format after all.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the [notes of `parse_ini_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#refsect1-function.parse-ini-file-notes),

> Characters ?{}|&~!()^" must not be used anywhere in the key

Raw mode does not lift this restriction. While `$` is not included in that list, am am pretty positive this is just missing in the doc and this DOES apply to `$`as well.

Comment: `$` seems to be used for [value interpolation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#example-2175)

Comment: Yes but that does only specify its usage in values. The OP is using it in a key, which is not defined in the docs. But as all other characters used in value interpolation are mentioned as being illegal in keys, I am confident that `$` should be included in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found a solution. I use the library PHP [component-ini](https://github.com/matomo-org/component-ini). And I use this function `setUseNativeFunction(false)` to prevent from error like this :

```
syntax error, unexpected '$'
```

And the code snippet to deal with my problem, I attach it above :

```php
    public static function parse(string $path) : array {
        $reader = new IniReader();
        $reader->setUseNativeFunction(false);
        return file_exists($path) ? $reader->readFile($path) : null;
    }`
```